# Dynamic route based on the selected page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page with a list of all the items. Which is http://localhost/myproject/items

Now I have item details pages which fetch the data from the database based on the item clicked 
The url of the item details page is  http://localhost/myproject/items/item_detail/3

I want to change the route from http://localhost/myproject/items/item_detail/3 
to http://localhost/myproject/items/{item title}

routes.php

```
$route['items/{item title}'] = "items/item_detail/$1";
```

How can i get the item title(from database) in place of {item title} in the above code

Please help

Comment: You should use [wildcards](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#wildcards).

Comment: Instead of `id` you should pass `item name` and display your details on that page using your `title` instead of `id`

Comment: @ Alexander Popov can u please tell me how wildcards can be used as item title is saved in the database